# How to set css error-styles programatically on a TextBox

Tags: java, css, gwt

Why can't I apply custom css styles to a single TextBox?

I'm trying to set some error styles on a single TextBox. What's wrong with the following implementation?

init:

```
static final String STYLES = ErrorRes.INSTANCE.css().style();

@UiField TextBox box;
box.setStylePrimaryName(STYLES);
```

Resource interface

```
interface ErrorRes extends ClientBundle {
    static final ErrorRes INSTANCE = GWT.create(ErrorRes.class);

    @Source("Error.css")
    Style css();

    interface Style extends CssResource {
        @ClassName("gwt-TextBox-error")
        String style();
    }
}
```

Error.css

```
.gwt-TextBox-error {
     border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure this is right: `box.setStylePrimaryName(STYLES);`. I was using GWT some months ago and I recall [setStylePrimaryName](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#setStylePrimaryName%28java.lang.String%29) updates dependent styles as well, there for you are setting a basic style and not an error style. On a second note, have you checked out the resulting HTML? It may give you more hints about the problem.

Comment: I tryed your case in code, it works well. See my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you whant to get gwt-TextBox-error style name on widget, you need set `box.setStylePrimaryName("gwt-TextBox");` - it's by default. And when error occured use `box.setStyleDependentName("error", true);` HTML will be *class="gwt-TextBox gwt-TextBox-error"*.
And to clear error style, use `box.setStyleDependentName("error", false);`

**OR**

You can use `addStyleName("gwt-TextBox-error")` and `removeStyleName("gwt-TextBox-error")` in a same way.

**---UPDATE---**

So, I tryed to run your case and it works well. At the first of all you need inject css from resources to page in runtime:

```
ErrorRes.INSTANCE.css().ensureInjected();
```

I use it in the begining of `onModuleLoad()`

Then, to add error style use:  `box.addStyleName(STYLES);`
and `box.removeStyleName(STYLES);` to remove it.

You can't use pair `setStylePrimaryName()` and `setStyleDependentName()` with bundled css becouse css name will be obfuscated.

Comment: Your 2nd option works perfectly if I place the `"gwt-TextBox-error"` css class inside my main css file. BUT I'd like to have a separate css file just for the error styles. And moreover, I do not want to use string literals with `addStyleName("gwt-TextBox-error")`, but getting the css class name from the `ErrorRes.INSTANCE` as written above. Anyhow using `addStyleName(STYLES)` does not work. Is there something wrong with my ClientBundle?